# How to find nodes to remove to isolate all other nodes in NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx

let's say I have an undirected graph with an arbitrary number of nodes and edges between them. Now I would like to remove the minimum number of nodes required to isolate all other nodes in this graph, i.e. turning each node into an orphan.

Is there an algorithm implemented in *Networkx* that achieves this in an efficient manner? And if such a function exists: Is it possible to assign weights to the nodes, so that the algorithm optimizes for the minimum number of removed total weight instead of minimum number of removed nodes?

Comment: What you're describing sounds like an extension of node cuts. The `all_node_cuts` function is probably the closest to your problem, but it determines the number of nodes to separate your graph into two or more components (doesn't guarantee each remaining node is an orphan). [Here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/connectivity.html) is the documentation for all functions related to connectivity. Maybe you can extend this or another function to suit your needs.

Comment: Alternatively you could check research work on network dismantling, see e.g. Generalized network dismantling (PNAS 2019).